# Why do I get this NullPointerException: a null object reference error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camera2

In Kotlin, I'm building an app that uses the camera. However, it crashes whenever I click the camera button either in emulator or on actual device. I get the error below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

This error-type is non-specific and has been asked a number of times by Java (not kotlin) lang users. The solution has typically been name mismatch between auth in manifest file and usage in code function call, however none of the proposed solutions have worked for me.

Here is the snippet in my code where I make the 'null reference' call:

```
var currentPath: String? = null
val TAKE_PICTURE = 1
val SELECT_PICTURE = 2

fun dispatchCameraIntent() {
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    if(intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null){
    var photoFile: File? = null
    try {
        photoFile = createImage()
    }catch (e: IOException){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    if (photoFile != null){
        // you must create a content provider matching the authority
        var photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.my_company.my_app.fileprovider", photoFile)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE)
    }
   }
}

    fun createImage(): File{
        val timeStamp =       SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMM_HHmmss").format(Date())//getDateTimeInstance()
        val imageName = "JPEG_"+timeStamp+"_"
        var storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        var image = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".jpg", storageDir)
        currentPath = image.absolutePath
        return image
    }
```

My xml file_paths file is at res>xml>file_paths.xml and is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path
    name="my_pictures"
        path="SDCARD/Android/data/com.my_company.my_app/files/Pictures"/>
```

Here is my full AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.my_company.my_app">

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity     android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity      android:name=".EmailSignIn" />
    <activity android:name=".RegisterUser" />
    <activity android:name=".ForgotPassword" />
    <activity android:name=".ViewController">
    </activity>


    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.my_company.my_app.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>


</application>
```

Here is the trace:

```
08-04 18:03:51.830 28205-28205/com.my_company.my_app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my_company.my_app, PID: 28205
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:584)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:558)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
    at com.my_company.my_app.ViewController.dispatchCameraIntent(ViewController.kt:91)
    at com.my_company.my_app.ViewController$onCreate$2.onClick(ViewController.kt:47)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: If you want hints on how to solve it, read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347569/139985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that is causing the problem.  It is in the `FileProvider` class.

```
    final ProviderInfo info = context.getPackageManager()
            .resolveContentProvider(authority, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    final XmlResourceParser in = info.loadXmlMetaData(
            context.getPackageManager(), META_DATA_FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS);
```

The stacktrace clearly shows that the NPE is happening for the `loadXmlMetaData` call, and it is happening because `info` is `null`.  (There is only one call-site for that method in the `FileProvider` class ...)

This evidence points to *something* being wrong with the way you have defined your `FileProvider`.

- Check / recheck the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider).
- Check for typos or mismatches in the manifest, etcetera.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Stephen. I am working in Kotlin and did not explicitly define the FileProvider class. I reviewed the documentation, but I still can't find what the issue is. Could it have something to do with my variable declarations, which I have now added to my code snippet show above?

Comment: The documentation talks about the `<provider>` config, and also about a security setting.  Check those.  They would apply to Kotlin ...

Comment: Checked. No luck. Anyone else know what the problem could be?

Comment: The issue was a typo in my authorities entry in AndroidManifest.xml